# Responsive random circle grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create the following random circle grid in HTML/CSS/JavaScript (excl. effects). I am not sure how to do this. Should I use absolution positioning in order to get this working/responsive? Looks likes a center point is pulling the circles...

[image]
*GIF captured from iTunes*

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle large">
    Hello
</div>
<div class="circle medium">
    Hello
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #111;
    margin: 10px;
}

.medium {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 3px #FC3358 solid;    
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 80px;    
}

.large {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 120px; 
    background: #FC3358;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: You need to use canvas for that kind of gravity effect

Comment: @Swordys Please add this comment as answer, so I can give you the points ;)

Comment: Sure thing, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `<canvas>` for that kind of gravity effect.